# Missing Dock and Desktop background is flashing on mac mavericks 10.9.5

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

My Mac Mini has been running with OS 10.9.5 for about 6 months. But now when I log in my desktop background is flashing with light fray colour for 1 second and the dock is missing. I restarted my machine more than 10 times, no results. The same is happening on every restart. No forums having any answers for this issue.

Comment: If the below answer doesn't help, you might want to ask the question over at http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following files in `user/library/preferences` :

```
Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist
Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
Preferences/com.apple.dock.db
Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.NUMBER.plist
Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.dock.NUMBER.plist
```

**Source:** [Post #8](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1650020) by [placidity](http://forums.macrumors.com/member.php?u=855306).